# Mass export layout with over 200 rasters

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.1

I have a long list of rasters (over the same area, but with different values) that I want to mass export, so that I have a JPG for each raster, along with a legend for that raster. You can see what I am trying to do in the picture below. However, this is something I have never done before, I have only exported maps manually, but I see that this task is way too big. Is there any (hopefully easy) way to export all of the images in the same style?

[image: arcgis-pro]

Comment: Have a look at the map series https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/layouts/map-series.htm

Comment: You would export Layouts through scripting by accessing methods on the [Layout object](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm#). Scroll to the bottom of the help page for code samples.